# Edit Debian 8 Boot file in sysresccd

Tags: linux, debian, boot, reboot

My dedicated server uses debian 8 but he cant boot anymore, now i started the rescue system (sysresccd) and my question is, is it possible to edit some files on the debian drive to fix the boot problems without any data losts?

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific regarding booting issue as "not booting anymore" may have many causes.
Please post any error that appears on the screen during booting process.

To be generic, you can use this command to see all volumes:

fdisk -l

You need to mount volume containing /boot directory but without knowing particular issue it' impossible to advice further.